# How to detect when a windows form is being minimized?

Tags: c#, winforms

I know that I can get the current state by WindowState, but I want to know if there's any event that will fire up when the user tries to minimize the form.

Answer (score 135):

You can use the Resize event and check the Forms.WindowState Property in the event.

```
private void Form1_Resize ( object sender , EventArgs e )
{
    if ( WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized )
    {
        // Do some stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this seems to be one of those places where [Exceptions can be swallowed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4933958/119527).

Comment: You also need this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Resize);

Answer (score 86):

To get in ***before*** the form has been minimised you'll have to hook into the WndProc procedure:

```
    private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    private const int SC_MINIMIZE = 0xF020; 

    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch(m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
                int command = m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0;
                if (command == SC_MINIMIZE)
                {
                    // Do your action
                }
                // If you don't want to do the default action then break
                break;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

To react ***after*** the form has been minimised hook into the `Resize` event as the other answers point out (included here for completeness):

```
private void Form1_Resize (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        // Do your action
    }
}
```

Comment: 0xF030 is when maximizing from normal window state.
0xF120 is when maximizing from the windows bar

Comment: Actually, this only catches the Minimize *Click* event! What you're looking for is WM_SIZE (0x0005) & SIZE_MINIMIZED (1)

Answer (score 18):

I don't know of a *specific* event, but the `Resize` event fires when the form is minimized, you can check for `FormWindowState.Minimized` in that event

Comment: This combined with a private "lastState" flag is the easiest way to go about it.

Answer (score 7):

For people who search for WPF windows minimizing event :

It's a bit different. For the callback use WindowState :

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        // Do some stuff
    }
}
```

The event to use is StateChanged (instead Resize):

```
public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.StateChanged += Form1_Resize;
}
```