# How can I tell when a user minimizes the form?

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [(C#) How to detect when a windows form is being minimized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052913/c-how-to-detect-when-a-windows-form-is-being-minimized)

First of all my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.MinimumSizeChanged += new EventHandler(Form1_MinimumSizeChanged);
        }

        void Form1_MinimumSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("1");
        }
```

so, my program idea is, when the program get minized i will do a system tray, but this event never happnd. how can i know when the user do a minize screen(minize the program).

i have tryed everything. any ideas?

Comment: This question can help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052913/c-how-to-detect-when-a-windows-form-is-being-minimized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MinimumSizeChanged has nothing to do with the form getting minimized.  MinimumSizeChanged has to deal with when the MinimumSize properties of the form are changed.

You want to check the Resize event of the form.

Answer (score 0):

In order to minimize to the system tray, add a [NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) control to your form. Now, override the OnResize method and check if your `WindowState` property is set to `FormWindowState.Minimized`.  If it is, `Hide()` your forms and show your notify icon.  Make sure to set the `Icon` property of the `NotifyIcon` as well.  Now just reverse the process for the case when the form is restored.