# What Event is used for Maximizing and Minimizing?

Tags: c#, forms, minimize, maximize

What Event is used for Maximizing and Minimizing for Windows Form?
I want to show message box when a Form maximizes and the from comes out of minimizing mode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052913/how-to-detect-when-a-windows-form-is-being-minimized

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what is your goal exactly ? what is not working (error messages/exception) ?

Comment: look at the link in the first comment (just read it and my answer was quite the same that the one in this post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Tested code

```
 private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Minimize");
        }
        else if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Maximize");
        }


    }
```