# Catch Peek Desktop button click event of desktop

Tags: c#, wndproc

I want to catch the event when my form is being minimized.

I have added WndProc messages for SC_Minimize for WM_SYSCommand.
But it doesn't hit when Win+D is pressed or Win+M is pressed or Peek Desktop button is clicked.

I have added keyboard hook for Win+D and Win+M but still troubled for the third option.

Is there any windows event or WndProc message I can track that will notify me as soon as the button is clicked.

My form size is changed If I use WM_Size so any are there any message which is directly linked to it.

Thanks,
Aman

Comment: don't forms have a minimize_Click()?

Comment: But I want to Handle some code on Form Minimize.
And How Can I handle that if user minimizes through some other method than clicking on minimize button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect when a windows form is being minimized?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052913/how-to-detect-when-a-windows-form-is-being-minimized)

Comment: @rinukkusu nope already mentioned that those are not working in my case.